# Is it possible to synch from our own Artifactory repo to Maven Central?

Tags: artifactory, maven-central

For some time, we have published all our artifacts to our own repository, which we host ourselves, using JFrog Artifactory.

We have some open source libraries we want to publish to Maven Central, and have come to the point where can publish every new version to Maven Central as a manual step.  Now, we want to automate this, and the two options seems to be to either integrate it into our CI workflow or to sync it from our repository.  Synching is the easier solution if we can make it work.  Sonatype provide some straight forward instructions for doing so with the Nexus Repository Manager here: https://central.sonatype.org/publish/large-orgs/sync/

However, Nexus does not run on Artifactory, so the question is:  **How do we sync from Artifactory to Maven Central?**  (Or is it even possible?  A confirmation that this is not possible would also be very valuable.)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, your use case is to sync the artifacts available in your Artifactory to the Maven Central or sync the artifacts available in Maven Central to your Artifactory? If it is latter, it can be done by configuring Maven remote repository in Artifactory to connect to Maven Central and cache all the artifacts in the Artifactory's remote repository cache.

Comment: It is the first.  We want to sync some specific artifacts in our own repository to Maven Central.

Comment: This is not possible from Artifactory

Comment: Thanks.  That is really nice to get confirmed!  I have not been able to find this conclusion anywhere. :)  (Feel free to post it as the answer to the question, and I will approve it as the solution.)

Comment: I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case is to sync the artifacts in Artifactory to the Maven central and it is not possible from the Artifactory side.